# Is "Hawth's Tools" available for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I am  looking for Hawth's Tools for ArcGIS 10.  Is it available?
I found that similar functions are in the new program Geospatial Modelling Environment (GME), but Hawth's Tools for ArcGIS 10 is not visible yet.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As you noted, most functionality of  Hawth's tools has been migrated to GME, which _is_ available for ArcGIS 10. Could you rework your question to ask something specific?

Comment: vaa!! Geospatial Modeling Environment (GME, before howths tools) is not an extension of arcgis 10 so why show it that?

Comment: http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm

Comment: In fact Hawth's Tools can be used with ArcMap 10.1 following installation through "Add In Manager" in ArcMap- i am using in 10.1

Answer (score 10):

Hawth's Tools will not be available for ArcGIS 10. From http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/tooldesc.php:

> [Dec 09] HawthsTools is now formally discontinued. The new software that replaces and improves upon Hawthstools is called the Geospatial Modelling Environment.

Comment: Link to GME: http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/

Comment: I can't vouch for all the tools, but with the optional VBA installed in my ArcGIS 10x, I have successfully installed and used Hawth's Tools.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Nov 2012:**

If you look on the [GME download page](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm), it appears it is now available for ArcGIS 10.0 SP4 and ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: Yes, "if you read" the download page. ArcGIS and R are dependencies but GME is a standalone software. This means that GME requires R and ArcGIS to run but is not available as a tool in either software.

Answer (score 1):

Hawth's Tools was earlier an add-on for ArcGIS. But now its called GME and its a separate program and uses R in the background. I.e. you need R and GME installed to use GME. You can email Hawthorne with any questions. He is pretty knowledgeable and helpful. Even Hawthorne advises you to use GME instead of Hawth's Tools. You need to use the latest version of R and latest version of GME to correctly run some functions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently attempted to install Hawth's Tools on Arc10 SP4 and it was successful and I've not seen any ill effects so far.
I will say that I'm only using it for a specific function, but I was able to install it and add it to my toolbar (Add from File) with no issues whatsoever.
Just another potential option for some to try.  It worked for me.